# In Django, what's the right way to pre-select a form option tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, html-select

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to create a SELECT menu on my template so I tried this ...

```
    <select id="website_id" name="website_id">
        <option value="">Select a website</option>
{% for website in websites %}
        <option value="{{ website.id }}" {{ 'selected' if website_id == website.id else '' }}>{{ website.path }}</option>
{% endfor %}
    </select>
```

but I get this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' if website_id == website.id else ''' from ''selected' if website_id == website.id else '''
```

Its choking on my "if" expression.  What's the preferred way to set the "selected" attribute of an option tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real right way is to use a Django form. But if you insist on doing it manually, you need an if tag

```
 {% if website_id == website.id %} selected {% endif %}
```

Comment: Even though I only have this one field in my form, I think it would pretty valuable to learn more about Django forms so after I get this to work perhaps I can return and do it the right way, which is what I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is like so:

```
{% if CONDITION %}A{% endif %}
```

So in your case, we would implement it like so:

```
    <select id="website_id" name="website_id">
        <option value="">Select a website</option>
        {% for website in websites %}
            <option value="{{ website.id }}" {% if website_id == website.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ website.path }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="qf">
    <option value="10th" {% if '10th' %} selected {% endif %}>10th</option>
    <option value="12th" {% if '12th' %} selected {% endif %}>12th</option>
</select>
```